# Is there a m. or mobile version of the Android Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I would like to read the answers to the Android - Stack Exchange site while on the read (in a bus or something).

Is there, or will there be, a mobile version of this site ? One which makes it easier to read on a smaller screen ?

Comment: For what it's worth, the standard site works quite well in the Android browser.

Comment: @ AlE.: It does but it should loose the right column when viewing it on a mobile phone (in landscape mode). You really don't need if screen space is minimal.

Comment: There are some browsing (read-only) apps: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/338/app-available-for-stackexchange-on-android-handset

Comment: Good call @OtherMichael... @Edelcom it's probably worth searching Stack Overflow's Meta site like this [search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mobile+browser).

Comment: Although I would admit that a site devoted to Android should be available in a more-android-friendly manner. I'm running afoul of this suggestion on my own android site, as well. Until mobile browsing is a good as web, we should have mobile-friendly layouts available.

Answer (score 6):

There actually is: [StackMobile.com](http://stackmobile.com/).

More information about this site can be found on its [StackApps page](https://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone).

Comment: Thx I will check this out, but it looks good. Just have to find out how I can see my own questions somehow.

Comment: http://stackmobile.com/site.php?site=android.stackexchange

Comment: Hey everyone! I am the author of StackMobile and I wanted to let you all know that I'm rolling out a much more improved version of the site that looks awesome on the Android platform. You can check it out [here](http://stackmobile.com/beta).

Answer (score 4):

Since circa 2011 all of the Stack Exchange sites have mobile-optimized versions.

If you're stuck in the desktop version you can force yourself into the mobile version by clicking the "mobile" link at the bottom of the page.

Conversely, if you find yourself in the mobile version and want to force your browser back to the desktop version, click the "full site" link at the bottom of the page.

The site should be able to work it out from your user-agent, though.